# Flutter how to get the value of a stateful widget's field?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, stateful

I have a Flutter app, which uses a `BottomNavigationBar`. I have made a class called `CustomBottomNavBar`, which describes my `BottomNavigationBar`. There, I have an integer field called `currentIndex`, which is the index of the currently selected icon on the navigation bar. I want to get this value from my main.dart class to display the indexth element of a `list<Widget>` called tabs, which contains the relative tabs.

The `CustomNavigationBar` class:

```dart
    class CustomBottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _CustomBottomNavBarState createState() => _CustomBottomNavBarState();
    }
    
    class _CustomBottomNavBarState extends State<CustomBottomNavBar> {
      int currentIndex = 0;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                              child: BottomNavigationBar(
                    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                    selectedFontSize: 11,
                    unselectedFontSize: 11,
                    selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
                    currentIndex: currentIndex,
                    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        activeIcon: Icon(Icons.home),
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.home,
                          color: currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[500],
                        ),
                        title: Text(
                          "Home",
                          style: TextStyle(color: currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[500]),
                        ),
                      ),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          activeIcon: Icon(Icons.explore),
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.explore,
                            color: currentIndex == 1 ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[500],
                          ),
                          title: Text(
                            "Explore",
                            style: TextStyle(color: currentIndex == 1 ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[500]),
                          )),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          activeIcon: Icon(Icons.subscriptions),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.subscriptions, color: currentIndex == 2 ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[500]),
                          title: Text(
                            "Subscriptions",
                            style: TextStyle(color: currentIndex == 2 ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[500]),
                          )),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          activeIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.mail,
                            color: currentIndex == 3 ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[500],
                          ),
                          title: Text(
                            "Inbox",
                            style: TextStyle(color: currentIndex == 3 ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[500]),
                          )),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          activeIcon: Icon(Icons.video_library),
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.video_library,
                            color: currentIndex == 4 ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[500],
                          ),
                          title: Text(
                            "Library",
                            style: TextStyle(color: currentIndex == 4 ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[500]),
                          ))
                    ],
                    onTap: (int index) {
                      setState(() {
                        currentIndex = index;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                );
      }

}
```

The main.dart:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  final List<Widget> tabs = [
    Center(child: Text("Home"),),
    Center(child: Text("Explore"),),
    Center(child: Text("Subscriptions"),),
    Center(child: Text("Inbox"),),
    Center(child: Text("Library"),),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home:  Scaffold(
            appBar: CustomAppBar(),
            body: tabs[2], //Here I would like to do something like tabs[customBottomNavBar.currentIndex]
            //),
            bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavBar()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: YOu can pass your custom index to `CustomBottomNavBar`, but I think in general you may want to go back and take another pass at tutorials for flutter navigation. I think you're making it unnecessarily hard on yourself. In general, I'd suggest giving each page an ID, and you can check the bottom nav bar to see if your ID matches to decide what to highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your value from main to CustomNavigationBar through a constructor and the access it as a local variable.

Here is a resource:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html

Take a look at the second samples to how set up your constructor and how to access the variable. (widget.YOUR_VAR_NAME).

If you want to take data out of your widget into main then you do the following:
1- Set up a getter method inside your widget class that returns the data you want.
2- Store an instance of your widget in your main function and then use it for getting the data or treat it as a widget.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var myWidget = CustomBottomNavBar();
  final List<Widget> tabs = [
    Center(child: Text("Home"),),
    Center(child: Text("Explore"),),
    Center(child: Text("Subscriptions"),),
    Center(child: Text("Inbox"),),
    Center(child: Text("Library"),),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home:  Scaffold(
            appBar: CustomAppBar(),
            body: tabs[2], //Here I would like to do something like tabs[myWidget.currentIndex]
            //),
            bottomNavigationBar: myWidget),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this solve your problem

Comment: How can I set up a getter?

Answer (score 1):

In this declarative programming pattern, you cannot ask questions to widgets. Widgets have to initiate actions. One thing you can do is to give a function for your widget to call:

```
bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavBar(
  onChange: (pageId) {
    print("we're at page $pageId now");
  }
)
```

Once you write this code, when you do quick fix (Alt+Enter in IntelliJ, Ctrl+. in VSCode) on `onChange` here, it will create the event handler parameter with the correct type. Later you can call it in your `CustomBottomNavBar` widget code.